# Overlapping grid element in backward compatible CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

I got a layout that has to be converted into HTML and CSS. A part of the layout requires a text block in a two column layout that leaves its section and not only overlaps into the next section but may also pass through it if the text size reuqires it.
See the layout example:
[Layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0usVA.jpg)

Sections: red, green

Text blocks: blue

Other blocks: yellow

Footer: black

As the text may vary in the overlapping text block, the footer should either be directly below that text block or - in case it does not pass entirely through the second section - directly below the second section. I hope this is understandable.

The challenge is to do this with backwards compatible CSS und HTML so even older browsers may display it correctly. This way I can only think of a fixed height for the first section and a visible overflow but then the footer's position would not grow with the text block.
Does anybody have another idea?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The main question is what browsers do you actually wanna support? IE is deprecated for a year. Even IE supported basic CSS-Grid while it fully supported Flexbox. If you want to support browsers for pre-2000 then it is an entirely different challenge while the cost/usage value is very questionable...

Comment: How many sections are there in that diagram? And if there is only one text element how is the amount it is to be longer in the first column than the second determined?